# How to get XML with header (<?xml version="1.0"...)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

Consider the following simple code which creates an XML document and displays it.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("root");
xml.AppendChild(root);
XmlComment comment = xml.CreateComment("Comment");
root.AppendChild(comment);
textBox1.Text = xml.OuterXml;
```

it displays, as expected:

```
<root><!--Comment--></root>
```

It doesn't, however, display the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

So how can I get that as well?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Create an XML-declaration using [XmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createxmldeclaration.aspx):

```
XmlNode docNode = xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xml.AppendChild(docNode);
```

Note: please take a look at the documentation for the method, **especially** for `encoding` parameter: there are special requirements for values of this parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was automatic.

Comment: +1. Please note that expecting "Utf-8" is mismatch with encoding of string  (see +1 Nicholas Carey answer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. But I'm `OuterXml`ing it and using that. Or am I missing something and there is a problem even then?

Comment: @ispiro  `string  s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root/>"` is a lie to some extent (encoding of the `string` in C#/.Net is not UTF8). Depending on the rest of your code/usage it may or may not be a problem (i.e. if you save it to fail as UTF16 you are in trouble).

Answer (score 17):

You need to use an XmlWriter (which writes the XML declaration by default). You should note that that C# strings are UTF-16 and your XML declaration says that the document is UTF-8 encoded. That discrepancy can cause problems. Here's an example, writing to a file that gives the result you expect:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("root");
xml.AppendChild(root);
XmlComment comment = xml.CreateComment("Comment");
root.AppendChild(comment);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
  Encoding           = Encoding.UTF8,
  ConformanceLevel   = ConformanceLevel.Document,
  OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
  CloseOutput        = true,
  Indent             = true,
  IndentChars        = "  ",
  NewLineHandling    = NewLineHandling.Replace
};

using ( StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("output.xml") )
using ( XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw,settings))
{
  xml.WriteContentTo(writer);
  writer.Close() ;
}

string document = File.ReadAllText( "output.xml") ;
```

Comment: How do you set column width using this code and can I use this in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 7):

```
XmlDeclaration xmldecl;
xmldecl = xmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

XmlElement root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
xmlDocument.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root);
```

Comment: Thanks. `InsertBefore` looks useful.

Answer (score 0):

Define more than one Element

```
Dim V As Object
Set V = xmlDoc.createElement("V")
V.Text = "0"
rootElement.appendChild V
```