# Missing xml header when convert json to xml in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

I create simple c# code to convert json to xml but there is an issue.
Check the result that miss xml header(version and encoding)

```
string json = "{\"name\":\"JSON\",\"integer\":1,\"double\":2.0,\"boolean\":true,\"nested\":{\"id\":42},\"array\":[1,2,3]}";
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root", true);
string xmlString = doc.InnerXml;
Console.log(xmlString);
```

Result

```
<root><name>JSON</name><integer>1</integer><double>2</double><boolean>true</boolean><nested><id>42</id></nested><array>1</array><array>2</array><array>3</array></root>
```

Comment: By default the header is not created when you generate xml from json. You can add header declaration manually. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839630/how-to-get-xml-with-header-xml-version-1-0) might help you.

Comment: I think the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840090/3744182) to [How to get XML with header (<?xml version=“1.0”…)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14839630/3744182), which is to write the `XmlDocument` using the `XmlWriter` returned by `XmlWriter.Create()`, is the better answer.  In fact I think this may be a duplicate; agree?

Comment: Demo of using [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840090/3744182) here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rocu0f